# Как узнать количество строк исправленных средой программирования VS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

У нас по дисциплине "Метрология, стандартизация, сертификация программного обеспечения" выдали следующие задание: узнать метрики кода (кол-во строк, **кол-во исправленных строк**).

Пока искал по сети узнал, что такую информацию можно получить только из managed project.
Также нашел программу **SourceMonitor** которая **считает** кол-во строк, комментариев и **множество другого, но кол-во строк исправленный средой программирования нет**(

Comment: git diff годится?

Comment: просмотрел информацию по git diff и думаю что это не то

Comment: Может я чего-то не знаю, но как у Вас среда программирования сама исправляет строки? Она же только подсвечивает ошибки, оставляя их исправление на Вашу ответственность, разве нет? Или современные среды уже и код правят на своё усмотрение?

Comment: @V-Mor - так-то Студия может сама перелопатить весь код. удалив, например, ненужные неймспейсы, изменив кейсинг и многое другое. Конечно, по команде девелопера. См. например, Run Code Cleanup.

Comment: git diff позволяет получить количество изменённых строк между коммитами. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2528111/5045688 - Дело за малым: начать пользоваться системой контроля версий и регулярно делать коммиты.